# A simple inequality involving the entropy function $H(x)$.

Tags: inequality, entropy

I came across the following simple inequality when I was working on a proof. I would like to know if it's a known inequality and used anywhere.

$H(x) > (\ln x)\times (\ln (1-x)), 0 < x < 1.$

The proof goes as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
H(x)&=&-x\ln x -(1-x)\times \ln(1-x)\\
    &=& -x \ln x + (x-1)\times \ln (1-x),
\end{eqnarray}
and since $-x \ln x > 0, 0 < x < 1,$ and $x-1 \ge \ln x, \forall x >0,$ 
\begin{eqnarray}
    H(x)&\ge& (x-1)\times \ln (1-x)\\ 
    &\ge &(\ln x)\times (\ln (1-x)). 
\end{eqnarray}

Any comments would be welcome.

Comment: The inequality does not hold (simple to check). However, plotting $\ln (x) \ln(1-x)$ indicates that it is actually a good approximation (not bound) of the entropy function.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by a simple check? Tx.

Comment: $-2>-3$ does not imply $-2\times-5>-3\times-5$. Similarly here as $\ln(1-x)<0$, multiplying by $\ln x$ does not give a smaller number than multiplying by $x-1$, (both being negative).

Comment: That makes sense—Tx. I've fixed the proof and will post it after I go over it.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this inequality was proved in the following article:

M Bahramgiri and O Naghshineh Arjomand. A simple proof of the entropy inequality. RGMIA research report collection, 3(4), 2000.

The same article also provides an upper bound.

Here is the 2-sided inequality that is proved in this article.

$(\ln x)(\ln (1-x)) \le H(x) \le (\ln x)(\ln (1-x))/\ln 2, 0 < x < 1.$

A more elementary proof of the left inequality is provided as follows:

Writing out the entropy function and dividing both sides of the desired  inequality by $(\ln x)(\ln (1-x)),$ (which is positive), gives

$1 \le \frac{-x}{\ln (1-x)} + \frac{-(1-x)}{\ln x}, 0 < x < 1.\,\,\, (1)$

Using the logarithmic inequality $\ln y > (y-1)/\sqrt{y};\, 0 < y < 1$ with $y=x$ and $y= 1-x$ implies

$\sqrt{x} +\sqrt{1-x} < \frac{-x}{\ln (1-x)} + \frac{-(1-x)}{\ln x}\,\,\, (2)$.

Now, it is not difficult to verify that $1\le \sqrt{x} +\sqrt{1-x}, 0 < x < 1$ and this together with $(2)$ implies $(1),$ which then implies the desired entropy inequality.